# ERROR: libfaac not found while compiling FFMPEG library

Tags: android, compilation, ffmpeg, android-ndk, libfaac

I was trying to compile FFMPEG library under ubuntu for android with including all possible codecs.
i followed this tutorial http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/.
but when i execute ./build_android.sh it gives me this Error:

> root@AK-74:/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/sources/ffmpeg-3.0# ./build_android.sh 
>   ERROR: libfaac not found
>
> If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
>   version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
>   ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
>   Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
>   solve the problem.

Here is my build_android.sh content:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86

function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-version3 \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
    --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
    --enable-libfaac \
    --enable-libgsm \
    --enable-libmp3lame \
    --enable-libtheora \
    --enable-libvorbis \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-libxvid \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j4
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

Comment: Are you sure the makefiles have a rule to make `libfaac` ?

Comment: I don't know .what do you mean by a rule. can you explain more please. I can add the Makefile if that can help. Thank you

Comment: I downloaded the library from here https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Please [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148554/unknown-option-enable-libfaad-error-libfaac-not-found-while-configuring-f) and see if that helps you out. If it doesn't, i'll track down what you're missing...

Comment: Ok @Shark thank you i will give it a try

Comment: You're probably just missing a few dependancies, the link I gave you should sort that out.

Comment: Can't fix it the same error appears again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it to work . The problem was that it can't find the lib's location.
I typed this command : locate libfaac. and from the output i realized that its under "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/" :

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfaac.a
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfaac.so
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfaac.so.0
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfaac.so.0.0.0

so what i did next is adding this line to "./build_android.sh" to tell it to look there:

> --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

so the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86

function build_one
{
echo $PREFIX
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--enable-nonfree \
--disable-symver \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-version3 \
--enable-shared \
--enable-libmp3lame \
--enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb \
--enable-libtheora \
--enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-libxvid \
--enable-libgsm \
--enable-libfaac \
--extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j4
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

Answer (score 1):

[libfaac sucks](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#Whichencoderprovidesthebestquality). Remove `--enable-libfaac` and `--enable-nonfree`. You can use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder instead and you won't need an additional external library to use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying does FFmpeg have AAC encoder by default ?. i tought i should compile it with it.

Comment: @SaidTagnit Yes. FFmpeg has its own AAC encoder: `-c:a aac`.

Comment: The link you gave contradicts what you said (that libfaac sucks). That page says: "For AAC-LC: libfdk_aac > Native FFmpeg AAC encoder (aac)." libfdk_aac is better than the native AAC encoder.

Answer (score 0):

install faac-1.26-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm and faac-devel-1.26-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm from below link.

```
http://pkgs.repoforge.org/faac/
```

Answer (score 0):

Install libfdk-aac-dev to resolve this error

`apt install libfdk-aac-dev`